# Assert "at least one item in the result collection matches predicate"

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-2.6

I want to assert that at least one item of a collection matches a given predicate with NUnit. I already asserted that the number of items is greater than 0, so it suffices to mimic the behavior of LINQ's `Any()` method.

I'm looking for something alike:

```
Assert.That(resultEnumerable, Is.Any.Matching(x => x.Property == "x"));
```

Or at least for:

```
Assert.That(resultEnumerable.Select(x => x.Property), Is.Any.EqualTo("x"));
```

Unfortunately, there seems to be only a `Is.All` constraint and no equivalent `Is.Any` - what am I missing?

Note: I don't want the much less readable:

```
Assert.That(resultEnumerable.Any(x => x.Property == "x"), Is.True);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about one of these?

```
Assert.That (resultEnumerable, Has.Some.Property ("Property").EqualTo ("x"));
Assert.That (resultEnumerable, Has.Some.Matches<X> (x => x.Property == "x"));
```

Answer (score 3):

I found:

```
Assert.That (resultEnumerable.Select (x => x.Property), Has.Some.EqualTo ("x"));
```

**Would still prefer a solution where I do not need the `Select()` anymore.**